# How do you set a maximum number value for a textfield in Swift that's flexible?

Tags: swift

I would like to use the

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
}
```

I'm fetching a number from firebase which will be the maximum they will be allowed to type into a textfield. Fetching the number is easy, how do I set this maximum for the `UITextField`?

Answer (score 0):

Just make a class and fill maximum number in storyboard as like:

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class CustomTextField: UITextField {
    
  
    @IBInspectable var maxLength: Int = Int.max {
        didSet {
            addTarget(self, action: #selector(limitLength), for: .editingChanged)
        }
    }
    

    
    override func didMoveToWindow() {
        super.didMoveToWindow()
        addTarget(self, action: #selector(limitLength), for: .editingChanged)
    }
    
    @objc private func limitLength() {
        guard let prospectiveText = text, prospectiveText.count > maxLength else {
            return
        }
        let selection = selectedTextRange
        text = String(prospectiveText.prefix(maxLength))
        selectedTextRange = selection
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622527-didmovetowindow **The default implementation of this method does nothing. Subclasses can override it to perform additional actions whenever the window changes.** There is no need to call super. Btw You don't need didSet and/or to add target when maxLength value changes. `@IBInspectable var maxLength: Int = .max`

Comment: Regarding the question thats being asked I think OP is trying to create an integer field and limit its maximum value (not the number of characters).

Answer (score 0):

you can use textField value;

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
if textField.text.count <= maximumNumberOfCharachters {
...
}
return false
}
```